# Update of RelationshipEntity resets values of various other rich relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, relationship, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

## 1. Problem summary

When I update an attribute of a single, existing Neo4j `RelationshipEntity`, the actual values of various other rich relationships of same type are suddenly replaced by their old, former status of values. It *seems* as if a transaction is rolled back. My expectation is that only the attribute of the `RelationshipEntity` under inspection is updated and all other relationships are untouched.

## 2. Initial situation

- running with Neo4j 3.4.7, Spring Boot v2.0.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.9.RELEASE
- no explicit usage of transactions
- reduced graph schema:

[image: reduced graph schema]

## 3. Target-actual comparison

### 3.1. Chronological sequence

The simplified use case according the graph schema can be summarized as following:

- Identify all `ClassC` nodes
- For them find various related `ClassB` (via `ClassA`)
- For each identified `ClassB` create a `ClassD` including relationship to `ClassB` and a rich relationship `CDMapping` to `ClassC`)

### 3.2 Expected / positive result

The complete described block works fine for the first run. Various `RelationshipEntitys` between `ClassC` and `ClassD` with the attribute "Default Value" are setup, the last rich relationship receives intended the value "Special Value".

[image: after first run]

### 3.3 Detailed problem

When it comes to the second block cycle – exactly by saving the first new `RelationshipEntity` between `ClassC` and `ClassD` - the attributes of the previous run are unexpected set back to "Default Value", replacing the original "Special Value".

[image: during second run]

### 3.4 Neo4j generated queries

The following queries are executed by Neo4j in this moment, triggered by the relevant `cdMappingDAO.save(cdMapping);`:

```
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId WITH row,startNode MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId CREATE (startNode)-[rel:`MAPS_TO`]->(endNode) SET rel += row.props RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, {type} as type with params {type=rel, rows=[{startNodeId=91, relRef=-45, endNodeId=115, props={attribute=Default Value}}]}
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (startNode) WHERE ID(startNode) = row.startNodeId WITH row,startNode MATCH (endNode) WHERE ID(endNode) = row.endNodeId MERGE (startNode)-[rel:`CONTAINS`]->(endNode) RETURN row.relRef as ref, ID(rel) as id, {type} as type with params {type=rel, rows=[{startNodeId=88, relRef=-49, endNodeId=115, props={}}, {startNodeId=92, relRef=-51, endNodeId=91, props={}}, {startNodeId=88, relRef=-54, endNodeId=93, props={}}, {startNodeId=89, relRef=-56, endNodeId=94, props={}}, {startNodeId=92, relRef=-57, endNodeId=90, props={}}]}
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`ClassA`:`Entity` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=92, props={name=Class A}}]}
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`ClassB`:`Entity` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=88, props={name=Class B1}}, {nodeId=89, props={name=Class B2}}]}
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`ClassD`:`Entity` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=115, props={}}, {nodeId=93, props={}}, {nodeId=94, props={}}]}
UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`ClassC`:`Entity` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=90, props={name=Class C1}}, {nodeId=91, props={name=Class C2}}]}
UNWIND {rows} AS row MATCH ()-[r]-() WHERE ID(r) = row.relId SET r += row.props RETURN ID(r) as ref, ID(r) as id, {type} as type with params {rows=[{relId=104, props={attribute=Default Value}}, {relId=106, props={attribute=Default Value}}], type=rel}
```

## 4. To be solved challenge

Can you please give me an advice why and by what component the attribute values are reset? How can I ensure, that the `RelationshipEntity` under inspection is updated only? Many thanks in advance for pointing me into the right direction!

## 5. Code snippets

### 5.1 GraphHandler

```
@Component
public class GraphHandler implements CommandLineRunner {
  private ClassADAO classADAO;
  private ClassBDAO classBDAO;
  private ClassCDAO classCDAO;
  private ClassDDAO classDDAO;
  private CDMappingDAO cdMappingDAO;
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


  @Autowired
  public GraphHandler(ClassADAO classADAO, ClassBDAO classBDAO, ClassCDAO classCDAO, ClassDDAO classDDAO, CDMappingDAO cdMappingDAO, SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.classADAO = classADAO;
    this.classBDAO = classBDAO;
    this.classCDAO = classCDAO;
    this.classDDAO = classDDAO;
    this.cdMappingDAO = cdMappingDAO;
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }


  public void run(String... args) {
    createInitialModel();
    runUseCase();
  }


  private void createInitialModel() {
    ClassA classA = new ClassA("Class A");
    ClassB classB1 = new ClassB("Class B1");
    ClassB classB2 = new ClassB("Class B2");
    ClassC classC1 = new ClassC("Class C1");
    ClassC classC2 = new ClassC("Class C2");

    classA.getClassBs().addAll(Arrays.asList(classB1, classB2));
    classA.getClassCs().addAll(Arrays.asList(classC1, classC2));

    classADAO.save(classA);
    classBDAO.save(classB1);
    classBDAO.save(classB2);
    classCDAO.save(classC1);
    classCDAO.save(classC2);
  }


  private void runUseCase() {
    Iterable<ClassC> classCs = classCDAO.findAll();
    for (ClassC classC : classCs) {

      ClassD rememberedClassD = null;
      List<ClassB> classBs = classBDAO.findClassBSelection(classC.getId());
      for (ClassB classB : classBs) {

        ClassD classD = new ClassD();
        classD.setClassB(classB);
        classB.getClassDs().add(classD);
        classDDAO.save(classD);
        rememberedClassD = classD;

        CDMapping cdMapping = new CDMapping(classC, classD, "Default Value");
        cdMappingDAO.save(cdMapping); // <-- here the problem occurs
      }

      // choosing the last created relationship (ClassC-ClassD) and mark it
      CDMapping relationship = cdMappingDAO.getRelationshipByClassCAndClassD(classC.getId(), rememberedClassD.getId());
      relationship.setAttribute("Special Value");
      cdMappingDAO.save(relationship);
    }
  }
}
```

### 5.2 CDMapping

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "MAPS_TO")
public class CDMapping {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @StartNode
  private ClassC classC;

  @EndNode
  private ClassD classD;

  private String attribute;

  public CDMapping(ClassC classC, ClassD classD, String attribute) {
    this.classC = classC;
    this.classD = classD;
    this.attribute = attribute;

    classC.getCdMappings().add(this);
    classD.getCdMappings().add(this);
  }

  // default constructor, getter and setter here
}
```

### 5.3 ClassA

```
@NodeEntity
public class ClassA extends Entity {
  private String name;

  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
  private List<ClassC> classCs = new ArrayList<>();

  @Relationship(type = "MAPS_TO")
  private List<ClassB> classBs = new ArrayList<>();

  // default constructor, getter and setter here
}
```

### 5.4 ClassB

```
@NodeEntity
public class ClassB extends Entity {
  private String name;

  @Relationship(type = "MAPS_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private List<ClassA> classAs = new ArrayList<>();


  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS")
  private List<ClassD> classDs = new ArrayList<>();

  // default constructor, getter and setter here
}
```

### 5.5 ClassC

```
@NodeEntity
public class ClassC extends Entity {
  private String name;

  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private ClassA classA;

  @Relationship(type = "MAPS_TO")
  private List<CDMapping> cdMappings = new ArrayList<>();

  // default constructor, getter and setter here
}
```

### 5.6 ClassD

```
@NodeEntity
public class ClassD extends Entity {
  @Relationship(type = "CONTAINS", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private ClassB classB;

  @Relationship(type = "MAPS_TO", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  private List<CDMapping> cdMappings = new ArrayList<>();

  // default constructor, getter and setter here
}
```

## Update

### 5.7 CDMappingDAO

```
@Repository
public interface CDMappingDAO extends Neo4jRepository<CDMapping, Long> {

  @Query("MATCH (classC:ClassC)-[relationship:MAPS_TO]-(classD:ClassD) WHERE id(classC)={classCId} AND id(classD)={classDId} RETURN classC, relationship, classD;")
  CDMapping getRelationshipByClassCAndClassD(@Param("classCId") Long classCId, @Param("classDId") Long classDId);
}
```

### 5.8 ClassADAO / ClassCDAO / ClassDDAO

```
@Repository
public interface ClassADAO extends Neo4jRepository<ClassA, Long> {
}
```

Except for the first `Neo4jRepository` type the `ClassCDAO` and `ClassDDAO` are identical.

### 5.9 ClassBDAO

```
@Repository
public interface ClassBDAO extends Neo4jRepository<ClassB, Long> {
  @Query("MATCH (classC:ClassC)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:ClassA)-[:MAPS_TO]->(classB:ClassB) WHERE id(classC)={classCId} RETURN classB;")
  List<ClassB> findClassBSelection(@Param("classCId") Long classCId);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing one of your DAOs? Are those SDN Repositories?

Comment: @MichaelSimons I'd be glad to. You are right, the DAOs are SDN repositories. I’ve updated the question by chapters 5.7 to 5.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it seems there's a bug somewhere in OGM, but I have found two workarounds for your problem.

Workaround one leaves your code pretty much as it is:

Change `runUseCase` One is in your `GraphHandler` to save the `CDMapping` with depth 0:

```
private void runUseCase() {
  Iterable<ClassC> classCs = classCDAO.findAll();
  for (ClassC classC : classCs) {

    ClassD rememberedClassD = null;
    List<ClassB> classBs = classBDAO.findClassBSelection(classC.getId());
    for (ClassB classB : classBs) {

      ClassD classD = new ClassD();
      classD.setClassB(classB);
      classB.getClassDs().add(classD);
      classDDAO.save(classD);
      rememberedClassD = classD;

      CDMapping cdMapping = new CDMapping(classC, classD, "Default Value");
      cdMappingDAO.save(cdMapping, 0); // <-- here the problem occurs
    }

    // choosing the last created relationship (ClassC-ClassD) and mark it
    CDMapping relationship = cdMappingDAO.getRelationshipByClassCAndClassD(classC.getId(), rememberedClassD.getId());
    relationship.setAttribute("Special Value");
    cdMappingDAO.save(relationship, 0);
  }
}
```

This leaves the "special" ones intact.

I'd rather suggest the following change, adding some more correct transaction boundaries.

Introduce a service class like `SomeGraphBasedService`. A dedicated class is necessary due to the fact how Springs declarative transactions work. Both methods, `createInitialModel` and `runUseCase` span now one transaction each and all DAO methods participate in it. Please take especially note on the comment, I only save the topmost parent class in `createInitialModel`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class SomeGraphBasedService {
    private final ClassADAO classADAO;
    private final ClassBDAO classBDAO;
    private final ClassCDAO classCDAO;
    private final ClassDDAO classDDAO;
    private final CDMappingDAO cdMappingDAO;

    public SomeGraphBasedService(ClassADAO classADAO, ClassBDAO classBDAO,
        ClassCDAO classCDAO, ClassDDAO classDDAO, CDMappingDAO cdMappingDAO) {
        this.classADAO = classADAO;
        this.classBDAO = classBDAO;
        this.classCDAO = classCDAO;
        this.classDDAO = classDDAO;
        this.cdMappingDAO = cdMappingDAO;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void createInitialModel() {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA("Class A");
        ClassB classB1 = new ClassB("Class B1");
        ClassB classB2 = new ClassB("Class B2");
        ClassC classC1 = new ClassC("Class C1");
        ClassC classC2 = new ClassC("Class C2");

        classA.getClassBs().addAll(Arrays.asList(classB1, classB2));
        classB1.getClassAs().add(classA);
        classB2.getClassAs().add(classA);
        classA.getClassCs().addAll(Arrays.asList(classC1, classC2));

        classADAO.save(classA);
        // No need to save them one by one, the releationships
        // take care of that while saving the parent class at the top
        /*
        classBDAO.save(classB1);
        classBDAO.save(classB2);
        classCDAO.save(classC1);
        classCDAO.save(classC2);
        */
    }

    @Transactional
    public void runUseCase() {

        Iterable<ClassC> classCs = classCDAO.findAll();
        for (ClassC classC : classCs) {

            ClassD rememberedClassD = null;
            List<ClassB> classBs = classBDAO.findClassBSelection(classC.getId());
            for (ClassB classB : classBs) {

                ClassD classD = new ClassD();
                classD.setClassB(classB);
                classB.getClassDs().add(classD);
                classDDAO.save(classD);
                rememberedClassD = classD;

                CDMapping cdMapping = new CDMapping(classC, classD, "Default Value");
                cdMappingDAO.save(cdMapping); // <-- here the problem occurs
            }

            // choosing the last created relationship (ClassC-ClassD) and mark it
            CDMapping relationship = cdMappingDAO
                .getRelationshipByClassCAndClassD(classC.getId(), rememberedClassD.getId());
            relationship.setAttribute("Special Value");
            cdMappingDAO.save(relationship);
        }

        Iterable<CDMapping> f = cdMappingDAO.findAll();
        for (CDMapping ff : f) {
            System.out.println(ff);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your command line runner becomes this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GraphHandler implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final SomeGraphBasedService someGraphBasedService;

    public GraphHandler(SomeGraphBasedService someGraphBasedService) {
        this.someGraphBasedService = someGraphBasedService;
    }

    public void run(String... args) {
        this.someGraphBasedService.createInitialModel();
        this.someGraphBasedService.runUseCase();

    }
}
```

While the first one is obviously a workaround, the other solution is the one I'd prefer in a real world scenario.

Anyway, the output of both is now as expected:

```
CDMapping{id=21, classC=ClassC{name='Class C1'}, classD=ClassD{classB=ClassB{name='Class B1'}}, attribute='Default Value'}
CDMapping{id=23, classC=ClassC{name='Class C1'}, classD=ClassD{classB=ClassB{name='Class B2'}}, attribute='Special Value'}
CDMapping{id=25, classC=ClassC{name='Class C2'}, classD=ClassD{classB=ClassB{name='Class B1'}}, attribute='Default Value'}
CDMapping{id=27, classC=ClassC{name='Class C2'}, classD=ClassD{classB=ClassB{name='Class B2'}}, attribute='Special Value'}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your spent effort and most valuable feedback. I will realize each of your proposals.

Comment: Thank for your detailed question. TBH, I need to thank @meistermeier for leading me through the investigation.
One tip, though: I have made the experience, that bidirectional mappings of relationships in Java, be it either JPA / ORM (Hibernate etc.) or OGM is very though to get right, from a users perspective but also on the mapping side. Your ClassCs and ClassDs keep track of the mappings and the CDMapping, too. You have to take very much care of keeping them intact. Maybe one direction is enough and the other side can be retrieved through a query?